# Java - Move position in 2d Array based on user input (and print out current position)

Tags: java, arrays, position

I have a program where the user writes in commands U,D,R,L. Based on the user commands I want position to move in 2D array. For example if the user writes UDUDU then I want the position to go 'up' 'down' 'up' 'down' 'up'. So far I have only managed to move it "once". I guess I have to update the current position, its here I have trouble and I need help!

For example use decides the size [3][3] and position [1][1].

```
  0 1 2 
0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
2 0 0 0
```

If the user presses UDUDU then the new position to be like this (the x to be +1 in this case)

```
  0 1 2 
0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
2 0 1 0
```

Here is the code:

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Enter length(x) and width(y)");
                    x = scan.nextInt();
                    y = scan.nextInt();

  int[][] roomsize = new int[x][y];//The array

  System.out.println("Enter the starting position");
                    x = scan.nextInt();
                    y = scan.nextInt();

  roomsize[x][y] = 1; //Starting position


System.out.println("Enter commands U(up), D(down), R(right) or  L(left)");//User input          
                   String command = scan.next();    

for (char directionCommand : command.toCharArray()){
                      move(directionCommand, roomsize, x, y);

                     }
                //Should I print it out here? It   
                /*for(int i = 0; i < roomsize.length; i++)
                   {
                      for(int j = 0; j < roomsize[i].length; j++)
                        {
                            System.out.print(roomsize[i][j]);
                            if(j < roomsize[i].length - 1)     System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }*/


public static void move(int i, int[][] roomsize, int x, int y){
                    int px = 0;//Current position
                    int py = 0;//Current position
                    switch(i){
                  case 'U': px+=1; break;//Is this the right way to update position?
                  case 'D': roomsize[x-1][y]; break;//Or this waY?
                  case 'R': roomsize[x][y+1] = 1; break;
                  case 'L': roomsize[x][y-1] = 1;break;                
                  default:; break;
                  }             
                    roomsize[px][py] = 1;//Do I set the new position like this?

 for(int i1 = 0; i1 < roomsize.length; i1++)
                       {
                          for(int j = 0; j < roomsize[i1].length; j++)
                            {
                                System.out.print(roomsize[i1][j]);
                                if(j < roomsize[i1].length - 1) System.out.print(" ");
                            }
                            System.out.println();
                        }
```

And also when and where exactly do I need to "Print out" the position in array? It seems wrong doing it exactly after the switch statement? Or? Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: It´s hard to follow what is actually happening here since the question is poorly formated.

Comment: What exactly is poorly formated? I want to "move" the current position (in this case =1) based on users input...

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense that you're only able to move once.  You have the user input outside of your for loop.

```
String command = scan.next();
```

Is read in before the loop then the length of command is used as the for loop

```
for (char directionCommand : command.toCharArray())
```

I would try using a while loop instead

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println("Enter length(x) and width(y)");
                    x = scan.nextInt();
                    y = scan.nextInt();

  int[][] roomsize = new int[x][y];//The array

  System.out.println("Enter the starting position");
                    x = scan.nextInt();
                    y = scan.nextInt();

  roomsize[x][y] = 1; //Starting position


while(true){
System.out.println("Enter commands U(up), D(down), R(right),  L(left), and Q(quit)");//User input
    String command = scan.next();
if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"){
    break;
}
    move(command.charAt(0), roomsize, x, y);
}
```

Comment: I just tried with the while loop, but it gives me same result. Only recognizes the first letter... charAt(0) returns only the first letter of the input right? If maybe I could make a loop from the input or something?